# My phone galaxy GT-I9003 is stuck in flight mode and not able to detect Sim card.

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, airplane-mode

I want to disable the airplane mode in order to return to normal state. After a long press on power button, I do have the "device options", however nothing happens when I press Airplane mode (airplane mode enable). I am stuck in airplane mode

Have you experience this? Is it a known bug? How can I disable airplane mode.

Comment: Which ROM you are using? Did you tried Basic fix "Restartng your Device"?

Comment: I had this problem, check http://www.inflightmagazine.co/?p=351

Comment: I think this device is not the galaxy-s, but the galaxy-sl. if so the tagging should be adjusted. http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9003_galaxy_sl-3761.php

Answer (score 1):

Go to SETTINGS > WIRELESS AND NETWORKS and uncheck AEROPLANE MODE from there.

If that doesn't work, remove the battery and SIM card, wait 1 minute and re-insert SIM + battery and restart.

Answer (score 1):

Run this on 
`adb`. This will toggle Airplane Mode.

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS
adb shell input keyevent 19 ; sleep 0.1; adb shell input keyevent 23; sleep 0.3; adb shell input keyevent 4;
echo "Toggled airplane mode";
```

[[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34399658/2620553)]